# Loading JSON exported from THREE.js editor

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

```
        var container;
        var camera;
        var scene;
        var renderer;
        var mesh;
        var loader;

        init();

        function init(){


            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHieght, 1 , 10000); 
            camera.position.z = 1000;
            //scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

            loader.load( "chesstable.js", function( mesh ) {

                mesh.scale.set( 1,1,1);
                scene.add(mesh);

            } );


            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }
```

Hello, I am trying to load scene ( some polygons and lights) exported from THREE.js editor as a json file. Browser seems to load json file but all I am getting is blank page. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be something like this

```
loader.load( "chesstable.js", function( geom ){
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what kind of material should it be there?

Comment: Do three.meshbasicmaterial()

Comment: Why? because it requires nothing else other than vertex pos. So if the model came in, youll see white, if not, the model did not come in.